# Testing in-app purchase with hosted content

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase, iap-hosted-content

We are adding in-app purchases to our app. I have created several products in iTunes Connect and most of these get listed in the app, except for the one that is using hosted content.

My problem is the following:
When I upload a hosted content package for the product the package has to be reviewed. Is there no way around this for testing purpose in the sandbox mode? I am not even sure that my package is good until I have tested it, so I really hope I don't have to wait for a review each time I make a small change to the package. Ideally the package should only need review when it is finished and ready for sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, it doesn't need review (even thought Xcode says so when you upload). I was missing the screenshot of my app with the product showed, which is weird because:

a) They say that it is only used for the review (so why do I need it for testing?)
b) I cannot actually take the screenshot with the product listed since it is not listed because it is missing the screenshot .............

My solution was to take a dummy screenshot, upload it, get the product listed in the app and take a new screenshot with the product listed.

Comment: Hi NobleK, 
I upload a hosted content package for the product the package has to be reviewed but I want to know that where it will save when I download it?in document directory ?? or we have to give path in our project for that please explain....Thanks